# How to make bootstrap popover fixed alongside with position:fixed elements?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this `<img>` tag in my html:

```
<img src="mascot.png" style="position:fixed;bottom:20px;right:20px" class="hvr-bob glowing green" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-container="body" data-content="Have any idea for PokoPoko?<br>Please tell us!" data-html="true"/>
```

When I scroll the mouse while the cursor is still hovering the image, the popover will separate from the image. How to make this popover also fixed alongside with the image? If can, I want this to be applied on all popovers which are attached on element `position:fixed`.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a div with position fixed and keep the image within it..like this

```
<div style="position:fixed;bottom:20px;right:20px">
    <img src="mascot.png" class="hvr-bob glowing green" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-container="body" data-content="Have any idea for PokoPoko?<br>Please tell us!" data-html="true"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried that before I'm asking here but no good. That won't work ... else you demonstrate it to fiddle so I can see that this is really a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `data-container="body"` to `data-container="img"`
I suppose you have multiple images like that so reference the `id` of that `<img>`